# DjangoでREST_APIを作ろうとしています。pathの取得方法を教えてください。

Tags: python, django, orm

URLは下記のようにしようとしています。

scheme://host:80/model_name/param1/param2/param3?order_by[]=field1%20acs&order_by[]=field2%20decs&limit=1&offset=2

order_byで指定されたfieldが
model_name(テーブル)のカラム名と一致しているかどうか判定したいです。

FuelPHPでは\Uri::segment(1)でmodel_nameを取得することが出来るのですが、
Djangoではこのようなメソッドはありますでしょうか。

また、model_nameがテーブルと紐づいている設計にしているのですが、
ORMからカラム一覧が取得できるようなメソッドを
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

単純にフィールド名のリストが取得したいってことであれば下記で取得できると思います。

```
[f.name for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields()]
```

下記を参照するとより詳しく理解できると思います。
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/